# Touchable components are not working in ReactNative when used inside ScrollView ->Flat-List ->map for iPhone 6s only

Tags: iphone, react-native, react-native-ios, touchableopacity

The onPress function of all touchables is not triggering the function when used inside ScrollView -> Flat-List -> map for iPhone 6s only. The code is working fine for all other devices (iPhone X, iPhone11 etc). The problem is resolved when I used onPressIn but it degrades the user experience.

```
<ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <FlatList
            data={props.seats}
            keyExtractor={(index) => `seater${index}`}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                { props.seats[index].map(
                    (object, i) => (
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("Helllo")}>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                  )}
            )}
          />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `ScrollView` as `Flatlist` already have scroll and for `horizontal` you can add it like

```
<FlatList
            data={props.seats}
            keyExtractor={(index) => `seater${index}`}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                { props.seats[index].map(
                    (object, i) => (
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("Helllo")}>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                  )}
            )}
            horizontal // add it here 
/>
```

Comment: I have already tried all the three methods suggested by you but they didn't work. Thanks though.